# How to change Windows Search shortcut to Ctrl+Ctrl?

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, windows-search

Apparently there is a [trick](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsdesktopsearchhelp/thread/e85fd2e1-a095-414a-837e-afe7ac7f0a97) to changing the default shortcut for Windows Search.  However, I'd like to change it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (e.g. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key twice, like Google Desktop does).  Is there a way to pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using the registry key because the control key is a modifier, not an ASCII character.

I'd use something like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to do this.  The following script would do this in AutoHotKey (assuming the default key combo is Control+Shift+f):

```
~ctrl::
if(a_PriorHotKey <> "~ctrl" or A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 400)
{
    KeyWait, ctrl
    return
}
WinActivate, Program Manager
send, #+f
return
```